# How to link an application written in Ada language?

Tags: ada, freertos, gnat

1. I have a running a board with FreeRTOS. What do I need to do if I want to link an application written in Ada language?
2. Does the SDK source code of FreeRTOS need to be recompiled with GNAT?
3. How to realize static link and dynamic link an Ada application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [_FreeRTOS + GNAT Ada compiled library_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59714074/230513).

Answer (score 2):

1. Your question reads as though you already have an application written in Ada and you want to run it on a board already running FreeRTOS; in that case, Trashgod’s [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59714074/freertos-gnat-ada-compiled-library) directly applies.
   Ada code relies on a runtime system (RTS), which is (usually) almost entirely written in Ada. Your application will very likely have been written in full (unrestricted) Ada, using exceptions and, possibly, tasking. The GNAT folk (AdaCore) have produced one bare-board RTS that supports exceptions, but only the [Ravenscar (and now Jorvik) tasking subset](https://blog.adacore.com/introduction-to-jorvik).
2. FreeRTOS itself shouldn’t need recompiling. If your other code is written in C++, it should be OK if your compiler is GCC.
3. FreeRTOS doesn’t support dynamic linking.